# Why didn't I get the My Lucky Day (daily climb) achievement?

Tags: technical-issues, achievements, mods, slay-the-spire

I'm playing Slay the Spire on Steam, with some mods. I launch the game, which shows the mod selection list, and I have the "enable achievements" mod enabled.

I completed three daily climbs:

- Two which I started, saved, and finished the next day (when it was no longer the climb-of-the-day)
- One which I started, saved, and completed the same day

In all three cases, I didn't get the achievement; why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What mods do you have installed?